# In C++ and range-v3, how to first transform a view and then convert it to a map?

Tags: c++, range-v3

Having any range as an input, how to first convert its elements to tuples and then save them in a `std::map` with `ranges::to`?

This code works and creates a vector of tuples:

```cpp
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

int main() { 
        auto v = ranges::views::iota(3, 10)
                | ranges::views::transform([](auto const &v){ return std::make_tuple(v, v*2); })
                | ranges::to<std::vector>();    
        fmt::print("{}\n", v);
}
```

Replacing `vector` by `map`, I'd expect to receive a map instead (with first elements of the tuples becoming keys and second elements becoming their values), but the code doesn't compile:

```cpp
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

int main() { 
        auto v = ranges::views::iota(3, 10)
                | ranges::views::transform([](auto const &v){ return std::make_tuple(v, v*2); })
                | ranges::to<std::map>();       
        fmt::print("{}\n", v);
}
```

I get:
`test.cpp:11:10: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('invoke_result_t<ranges::views::transform_base_fn, ranges::iota_view<int, int>, (lambda at test.cpp:9:30)>' (aka 'transform_view<ranges::iota_view<int, int>, (lambda at test.cpp:9:30)>') and 'detail::to_container_fn<detail::from_range<std::map>>' (aka 'closure<ranges::detail::from_range<std::map>, ranges::detail::to_container::fn<ranges::detail::from_range<std::map>>>'))`

Notes: I didn't find many examples of using `ranges::to<map>` in the internet, but in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74433668 there's working code where the result of `ranges::views::zip` is converted to a map. Since `zip` produces "tuple-like" elements, I expected my code to work too, but apparently it's not that straightforward.

Compiler is Clang++ v. 15.0.6, ranges is current master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `std::pair`, not a `std::tuple` ([working example](https://godbolt.org/z/hv14PffTe)):

```cpp
auto m = ranges::views::iota(3, 10)
       | ranges::views::transform([](auto const &v){ return std::make_pair(v, v*2); })
       | ranges::to<std::map>;
```

---

After all, while something like this is fine,

```cpp
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v;
std::map<int,int> M(v.begin(), v.end());
```

something like this is not

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>> v;
std::map<int,int> M(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Or, more simply as suggested in a comment,

```cpp
std::map<int,int> P{{std::pair<int, int>{}}};  // OK
std::map<int,int> T{{std::tuple<int, int>{}}}; // Error
```

Comment: Thanks, this principially helps. Two things however: (1) it only works for me if I explicitly specify map template arguments (`ranges::to<std::map<int, int>>`) and (2) I'd be very interested to know, why can't tuple be used. I'm accepting the answer though, because it solves my problem.

Comment: As regards (1), mine is a solution that works for C++17 on all 3 compilers, and you don't need to specify the template arguments; check your compiler versions and options. Concerning (2), it must have to do with some specilization or viability of conversion.

Comment: @Enlico regarding point number two, I believe it's because `std::map` uses a `std::pair`, not a tuple

Comment: @Enlico Indeed, switching to C++17 removes the requirement of template arguments specification.

Comment: @notsurewhattodo, yeah, CTAD is a C++17 feature.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso, I know that `sdt::map` uses `std::pair` but for some reason I gave for granted it was constructible from 2-`std::tuple`s too, because, after all, there's no reason for it not to offer that possibility through the API.